# How to extract the keys and values of a dictionary as a separate column in a data frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have two data frame which is like,

```
df:
   building  level      site          mac_location  gw_mac_rssi
0  2b        2nd-floor  crystal-lawn  lab           {'ac233fc01403': -32.0, 'ac233fc015f6': -45.5, 'ac233fc02eaa': -82}
1  2b        2nd-floor  crystal-lawn  conference    {'ac233fc01403': -82, 'ac233fc015f6': -45.5, 'ac233fc02eaa': -82}
```

I need to extract the keys of "gw_mac_rssi" as "gw_mac" and values of "gw_mac_rssi" as "rssi" which should be

```
required_df:
   building  level      site          mac_location  gw_mac                                            rssi   
0  2b        2nd-floor  crystal-lawn  lab           ['ac233fc01403','ac233fc015f6','ac233fc02eaa']    [-32.0,-45.5,-82]
1  2b        2nd-floor  crystal-lawn  conference    ['ac233fc01403','ac233fc015f6','ac233fc02eaa']    [-82, -45.5, -82]
```

I have tried with,

```
df['gw_mac'] = list(df['gw_mac_rssi'].keys())
```

whereas unable to get the required data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) for process each value separately:

```
df['gw_mac'] = df['gw_mac_rssi'].apply(lambda x: list(x.keys()))
df['rssi'] = df['gw_mac_rssi'].apply(lambda x: list(x.values()))
```

Alternative:

```
f = lambda x: pd.Series([list(x.keys()), list(x.values())])
df[['gw_mac','rssi']] = df['gw_mac_rssi'].apply(f)
```